# Conflicting node.js Express object/collection routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following Node Express routes...

```
get('/api/dogs')
get('/api/dogs/:id')
get('/api/dogs/breeds')
```

You can probably see the problem already. The routing gets confused when calling the 'breeds' route thinking I am trying to call the 'dogs/:id' route.

Is there a way to get around this? Or should I just create a unique route, something like 'api/dog-breeds'? I'd like to keep them all under the same resource because I am using the Express' modular 'router' object.

Comment: Change the order of the routes!

Comment: ^ it's that easy, just move the last one up

Comment: And read the documentation carefully!

Comment: Wow, didn't think the order would matter at all. Thanks! And yes, I'm guilty of not fully reading the documentation. :(